# How can i access to array key in twig view symfony 3

Tags: twig

I have a method that returns multiple arrays and I want to access to their data to manipulate them in `twig`:

<kbd>repository</kbd>

```
  public function getmemberlist($list){
    $memberId = explode('-',$list);
    $membres = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT m.nom, m.prenom, m.profile_pic
         FROM MainBundle:Member m
         WHERE m.id IN(:id)'
        )
        ->setParameter('id',array_values($memberId))
        ->getResult();

    return $membres;
}
```

<kbd>controller</kbd>

```
public function membreGroupeAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $str = $em->getRepository("GroupGroupBundle:Groupe")->findOneBy(array('id'=>1));
    $member = $em->getRepository("GroupGroupBundle:Groupe")->getmemberlist($str->getMembres());
    var_dump($member);



    return $this->render('@GroupGroup/layout/membres.html.twig',array("mem"=>$member));

}
```

this is the result of `var_dump($member)`

[image: var dump result]

everything is good until now but i didn't find how to manipulate the data in my twig. I've tried this but it shows me an error

<kbd>twig</kbd>

```
{% extends '@GroupGroup/Group/groupe_mur_base.html.twig' %}
{% block panel %}
{% for i in  mem %}
  {% for j in i %}
    {{ j[0].nom }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
<div class="jumbotron list-content" style="display: block;">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li href="#" class="list-group-item title">
            Liste des Membres
        </li>
        <li href="#" class="list-group-item text-left" id="listmembre" style="display: block;">
            <div class="image">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/User_for_snippets.png">
                <span id="membername">Juan guillermo cuadrado</span>
                <div><button id="btnajout" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button></div>

            </div>
            <div class="break"></div>
        </li>
        <li href="#" class="list-group-item text-left" id="listmembre" style="display: block;">
            <div class="image">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/User_for_snippets.png">
                <span id="membername">Juan guillermo cuadrado</span>
                <div><button id="btnajout" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button></div>

            </div>
            <div class="break"></div>
        </li>
```

<kbd>error</kbd>

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using 2 for-loops in your code,

```
{% for i in  mem %} {# here you are looping members #}
     {% for j in i %} {# here you are looping attributes of the member #}
         {{ j }} {# output is bg, wass, http://.... #}
     {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

If you want to display the name of the members you should only use one loop

```
{% for i in  mem %}
<div>
    <img src="{{ i.profile_pic }}" alt="{{ i.nom }} {{ i.prenom }}" title="{{ i.nom }} {{ i.prenom }}" />
    {{ i.nom }} {{ i.prenom }}        
</div>
{% endfor %}
```